# how to disable look up field on standard page layout page by selected picklist value (Not VF Page) on standard object(cases) in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

**how to disable look up field on standard page layout page  by
    selected picklist value  (Not VF Page)  on standard object(cases) in
    salesforce**

Comment: Could you please further explain your question.  When you say look up field, do you mean a field that represents a Look-up Relationship?  When you say disable, do you mean that you don't want that field to be visible, don't want it to be editable, or don't want the search functionality (magnifying glass)?  When you say by selected picklist value, could you please give an example of your intended functionality?

Comment: Thank You for giving time. A picklist has number of values and i want to show the look up field inside the page on some picklist values not all the values.example a picklist has a values(a,b,c,d,e). but i want to show to look up field on b,d values selection. But in another selection (a,c,e) it will remain hidden or disable on page layout of cases(standard object Page layout)